# Process not Listed by PS or in /proc/

Tags: linux, bash, process, shell-script

I'm trying to figure out how to operate a rather large Java program, 'prog'. If I go to its /bin/ dir and configure its setenv.sh and prog.sh to use local directories and my current user account. Then I try to run it via "./prog.sh start". Here are all the relevant bits of prog.sh:

```
USER=(my current account)
_CMD="/opt/jdk/bin/java -server -Xmx768m -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" -jar "${DIR}/prog.jar""
case "${ACTION}" in
    start)
        nohup su ${USER} -c "exec ${_CMD} >>${_LOGFILE} 2>&1" >/dev/null &
        echo $! >${_PID}
        echo "Prog running. PID="`cat ${_PID}`
        ;;
    stop)
        PID=`cat ${_PID} 2>/dev/null`
        echo "Shutting down prog: ${PID}
        kill -QUIT ${PID} 2>/dev/null
        kill ${PID} 2>/dev/null
        kill -KILL ${PID} 2>/dev/null
        rm -f ${_PID}
        echo "STOPPED `date`" >>${_LOGFILE}
        ;;
```

When I actually do ./prog.sh start, it starts. But I can't find it at all on the process list. Nor can I kill it manually, using the same command the shell script uses. But I can tell it's running, because if I do ./prog.sh stop, it stops (and some temporary files elsewhere clean themselves out).

```
./prog.sh start
Prog running. PID=1234
ps eaux | grep 1234
ps eaux | grep -i prog.jar
ps eaux >> pslist.txt
(It's not there either by PID or any clear name I can find: prog, java or jar.)
cd /proc/1234/
-bash: cd: /proc/1234/: No such file or directory
kill -QUIT 1234
kill 1234
kill -KILL 1234
-bash: kill: (1234) - No such process
./prog.sh stop
Shutting down prog: 1234
```

As far as I can tell, the process is running yet not in any way listed by the system. I can't find it in ps or /proc/, nor can I kill it. But the shell script can still stop it properly. So my question is, how can something like this happen? Is the process supremely hidden, actually unlisted, or am I just missing it in some fashion? I'm trying to figure out what makes this program tick, and I can barely prove that it's ticking!

Edit:

```
ps eu | grep prog.sh (after having restarted; so random PID)
50038    19381  0.0  0.0  4412  632 pts/3    S+   16:09   0:00 grep prog.sh HOSTNAME=machine.server.com TERM=vt100 SHELL=/bin/bash HISTSIZE=1000 SSH_CLIENT=::[STUFF] 1754 22 CVSROOT=:[DIR] SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3 ANT_HOME=/opt/apache-ant-1.7.1 USER=[USER] LS_COLORS=[COLORS] SSH_AUTH_SOCK=[DIR] KDEDIR=/usr MAIL=[DIR] PATH=[DIRS] INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc PWD=[PWD] JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_21 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1 SHLVL=1 HOME=[~] LOGNAME=[USER] SSH_CONNECTION=::[STUFF] LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1 _=/bin/grep OLDPWD=[DIR]
```

I just realized that the stop) part of prog.sh isn't actually a guarantee that the process it claims to be stopping is running -- it just tries to kill the PID and *suppresses all output* then deletes the temporary file and *manually inserts* STOPPED into the log file. So I'm no longer so certain that the process is always running when I ps for it, although the code sample above indicates that it at least runs erratically. I'll continue looking into this undocumented behemoth when I return to work tomorrow.

Comment: What does the following command output? `ps eu | grep prog.sh`

Comment: I'll edit it into the post, since it's about 1,000 characters too long to fit here. Although I might have to edit it slightly, since I don't think I can divulge that much information about the systems I'm on.

Comment: The process name may be java, not prog.  Have you tried looking for a java process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$!` PID is that of `su` since you're backgrounding it rather than your `$_CMD`. You should move the `&` inside the closing quote.

Use [`pidof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) or [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) to get your process' PID instead of using `$!`. If you're on a system that uses Upstart or has a similar daemon system, you should model your script after those and use the functions in `/lib/lsb/init-functions` or similar.

Comment: There must be more than meets the eye here. If I move the & inside the closing quote, then the task hangs, although it does show up on ps as "su [user] -c exec /opt/jdk/jre/bin/java -server Xmx768m -D[Java parameters and their values] -jar [...]/prog.jar >>[logdir]/log.file 2>&1 &" The console hangs, and ^C will do nothing. If I kill it via another terminal, the console unhangs, except that the only input that has any effect is ^C, which brings up another prompt. No other keys work. I'm not sure why this command is hanging, as it looks good as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's still terminating abnormally and irregularly, but I can at least tell what's going on now thanks to your & observation. I'm actually wondering how its original form works at all, if $! returns su's PID, but it must work in some fashion since that's the script used by production versions. At least I'm getting a PID and... oh, hey, the log files are now getting Java Exceptions and Stack Traces. I'm in business! Thanks.

Comment: @Hammer Bro.: You may already know this, but use the `reset` command (typing it blind, if necessary, after pressing enter or ^C) to make the terminal stop misbehaving after killing the program.

Answer (score 2):

As for the process not being visible, I encountered the same thing with java.
Try:

```
ps auxm
```

*(note: no dash!)*

It's probably a thread, which ps doesn't seem to show in most cases.